# "Бежать сломя голову" — происхождение поговорки

Tags: фразеология

Читала перлы из школьных сочинений, где попалось такое: "Он бежал, сломив голову".
Вдумалась в смысл этой поговорки. Почему — сломя голову? И почему "сломя голову" воспринимается просто как "очень быстро", "без оглядки", а "сломив" выглядит уже как курьез?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бежать сломя голову - очень быстро, стремительно бежать (нестись, бросаться).
1. Результат фразеологизации свободного сочетания со значением "потеряв голову", связанного с сочетаниями "сложить голову", с одной стороны, и "сложа руки" - с другой. На развитие современного значения повлияло также диалектное выражение "стремя голову", связанное со словом "стремглав". 2. Выражение возникло на основе существительного "сломиголова" (отчаянный смельчак)(с сайта www.gramma.ru)