# Бежать, сломя голову

Tags: фразеология

"Бежать, сломя голову" значит бежать очень быстро, без оглядки, можно сказать, убегать в панике. Но почему именно "сломя голову". Как мне кажется, "сломанная голова" может, скорее, стать следствием такого безоглядного бега.
Или же в основе этой поговорки лежит что-то другое? И, если да, то что?
Хотелось бы узнать происхождение поговорки "бежать, сломя голову".

Comment: Поскольку это фразеологизм, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вопрос уже был [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15513/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8), но ответ получен крайне расплывчатый.
*Бежать сломя голову* - все равно что *бежать стремглав*, то есть очень низко наклонив голову и ничего не видя по сторонам.

> *Стремглавъ*, наречие. Внизъ головою. (Словарь 1847)

Дополнение.
В Словаре Академии Российской (1789-94) сказано следующее :

> *Сломя голову бежать, скакать*. В просторечии. **Весьма быстро** бежать, ехать.

[Спринтер http://naturnike.ru/upload/blogs/13500d145d35b7afa9c2ff7bd78ee55c.jpg.jpg](http://naturnike.ru/upload/blogs/13500d145d35b7afa9c2ff7bd78ee55c.jpg.jpg)

Comment: У Черных приводится о.-с. наречие strьmъglavь: головой вниз-ногами вверх. Часть strьmъ имела значение "напротив, наоборот", также существовало выражение "стрьмъ  глаголати" - противоречить. Тогда в сочетании "стремглав" мы, образно говоря, имеем  не опущенную, а перевернутую и  противоречащую здравому смыслу голову. Поэтому  "бежать стремглав" - это, скорее, сложение двух значений: бежать быстро/стремительно и бежать, не контролируя себя. А вот в сочетании "бежать сломя голову" быстрота бега обозначена только неспособностью что-либо замечать или соображать.

Comment: *Стремглав* и *сломя голову* (при глаголе бежать) означают одно и то же: низко наклонив голову, не глядя по сторонам. Изначально именно так.  
Стремглав прямо соотносится со стремлением и стремительностью (вперед и вниз); сломя голову - практически то же самое.

Answer (score 2):

В разговоре, употребляя слово **голова**, мы зачастую имеем в виду не часть тела, а операционную систему. Например: «Включи голову!..» - начни рассуждать, думать. «Проветри голову!..» - избавься от лишних мыслей, по аналогии избавления от лишних запахов проветриванием комнаты. Бежать сломя голову, значит бежать не думая, находясь под воздействием сильной эмоции (страха, например). Почему не выключив голову, а сломя? Потому что эмоции прерывают  мыслительный процесс, ломают его. Принято считать, что эмоции – это **сердце**, а мысли - **голова**, поэтому можно «потерять голову и... влюбиться! ».

Answer (score 2):

Голова сломалась или вовсе потерялась - такое образное значение вкладывается в понятие "бежать сломя голову" или "сорвиголова". Сходными по смыслу являются выражения "очертя голову" (очертя себя магическим кругом) и "осеня крестом", когда человек, надеясь на помощь высших сил, ведет себя отчаянно и безрассудно.